# Python: Test if dictionary (dict) entry has been modified

Tags: python, dictionary, wrapper

I have written a small wrapper for the `dict` built-in class that loads entries (values) of a dictionary from `cPickle`d files as soon as the respective key is first accessed. When the dictionary is destroyed all loaded entries are written back to disk.

Now it would be convenient if I could check if any of the values has been changed and write out only those that in fact have been. **My question therefore is: Does a dictionary know if a value has been changed? Or is there a clever way to transparently implement this?**

For completeness I attach the code I use. It's called with the path where the files are stored (keys are used as filenames) and with a list of keys for which files exist.

```
import cPickle

class DictDB(dict):

  def __init__(self, path, folders):
    self.picklepath     = path    # path to files on disk
    self.folders        = folders # available folders
    self.loaded_folders = {}

  def has_key(self, key):
    return key in self.folders

  def get(self, key):
    if not key in self.loaded_folders.keys():
      if not key in self.folders:
        raise KeyError("Folder "+key+" not available")
      # load from disk
      self.loaded_folders[key] = cPickle.load(file(self.picklepath + key + ".cpickle2"))
    return self.loaded_folders[key]

  def __getitem__(self, key):
    return self.get(key)

  def close(self):
    for folder in self.loaded_folders.keys():
      # write back
      cPickle.dump(self.loaded_folders[folder], file(picklepath + folder + '.cpickle2', 'w'), 2)

  def __del__(self):
    self.close()
```

Comment: Yes, they're almost always `dict`s themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might approach it with a sort of publish-subscribe model, where the containing dictionary subscribes to each of the sub dictionaries (or other values). Then when one of them is edited, it notifies any dictionaries that contain it.

If you don't want them all deal with the wiring for that and are willing to allow the containing dictionary to only check for changes on access or at set intervals, you can have each contained object keep track of a `version` number.  Then when the containing dictionary is ready, it simply checks to see if that version number has changed.

A final possibility would be to have a way of reliably calculating hash values for contained objects in place.   This would let you write an external function and remove the need for the objects to track their own versions, but has its own complexities since you'll either need to overload `__hash__` on all of them or write another form of the `hash()` function that can identify the object and take some sort of intelligent hashed value from it

Comment: I ended up with something like your first suggestion; in the end this meant that I also had to wrap all `list` and `dict` objects that I store in the parent dictionary so that they notify the parent dictionary upon a change.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can overwrite the `__setitem__()` method to keep track of the changes of the values,  storing the changed values in a list, and use this list to choose the correct values to write out.

Comment: Seeing Janne's comment I noticed that I should have mentioned that the values themselves will not be replaced, but modified, meaning that `DictDB.__setitem()__` would not be called (I guess). -- But in the end you're right that I need to go one step further and use another wrapper of the dict class as values.

Comment: The problem is indeed that `__setitem()__` is not called when a object like a `list` or a `dict` that is stored as a value in the parent `dict` is changed.

Answer (score 0):

You could store two copies of each value: original state and possibly modified state. Then simply compare these with `!=` to choose which to write out.

Comment: That's certainly possible, but as the values are large objects, I'd rather not keep two copies of them. (The fact that they are so large makes me loading them each separately and only on request, otherwise I could just `pickle` the whole `dict`.)

Answer (score 0):

Memory permitting, you could retain a copy of the original values read from disk, and in the `close()` method compare the current values with the original values, only writing out the changes.

This method gives more freedom in what can be put into the dictionary, since the elements don't need to keep track of changes made to them.

Comment: Same idea as Janne, same comment from me :)